# Webscraping Endpoint

Tags: web, web-scraping

Hello I was wondering how i can find a hidden Endpoint of a website that stores product urls.

I tried getting the sitemap of the website but the website either does not have one or it is hidden and I cant find it. Also searched for

I hope someone could help me or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

A helpful resource to request from the server you are crawling is `/robots.txt`. Most hosts will serve this file, and it tells your crawler where it is allowed to go.

Comment: i ve tried that but this website does not have any helpful informations in it

Comment: Can you share it?

Comment: yea it has no page like that thats the problem